# User input java Eclipse repeated at start new line

Tags: java, eclipse, user-input

I'm trying to get rid of the user input at the start of the next line as shown below:
[image: Eclipse console output]

Any tips?

Please ignore the endmonth=beginmonth etc.

Comment: Do you mean where for example it's put 3 in  3Please. . .

Comment: Please show the relevant code in your question. Don't just link to external sites.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change how you are printing the input, try changing:

```
System.out.print(input1.next())
```

to

```
System.out.println(input1.next())
```

This should insert a newline character at the end of the input display and thus stop it appearing so jumbled.